# Insert HTML into a PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress

I need some help for this PHP array. Basically I have a simple dropdown selection in an admin area and I want to output a different number of stars on the page, based on the selection. So when I select 3* in the dropdown, the output will be three fontawesome stars on the page.

```
$this->select(
    'stele_hotel',
    __('Stele hotel', 'Nimva'),
    array('<i class="fa fa-star blue"></i>' => __('1*', 'Nimva'), '2*' => __('2*', 'Nimva'), '3*' => __('3*', 'Nimva'), '4*' => __('4*', 'Nimva'), '5*' => __('5*', 'Nimva')),    
    ''    
);
```

This is what I had in mind, but it doesn't work. In the dropdown it doesn't look so well, and it doesn't output anything.

Any help would be welcome, since I have so little PHP knowledge.

Comment: You should tag whatever framework you are using.

Comment: What HTML does this code output? Does the HTML not behave the way you expect (in which case focus on the HTML rather than the PHP) or does the PHP not generate the HTML you expect (in which case also tell us what HTML you expect it to output)

Comment: This is a wordpress theme I edited for a travel agency. So i want to show on the result page a number of stars, based on what the user selects in the admin panel, for that offer. So if I select 1*, i want to output on the page one star, as a FontAwesome icon. This is the code that i use to output on the page `<?php 
         if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_stele_hotel', true)): ?>
         <span class="stele"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_stele_hotel', true); ?></span><br>
         <?php endif; ?>`